# Which DAW is this?

Tags: software, daw, logic-pro

I saw this from a screenshot on a youtube video. Please help me find out which DAW this is.

[image: Please help me identify the DAW]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Apple's [Logic](http://www.apple.com/logicpro) in mixer view.

You can see another view of the mixer under the heading "Pro mixing in all its glory" [here](http://www.apple.com/logicpro/top-features/).